# Cross database UID management using a single parent database?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a number of MySQL databases that will at some point contain data records.

The databases are held on separate servers for a number of reasons not relevant to this question.
Clearly MySQL has the auto increment capability which can be used to assign unique identifiers to these records.

Because data is not stored in a single database, there needs to be a 'parent' database that creates and returns UID's for all records across the databases - therefore preventing UID duplication.

The cons I can foresee by using a 'parent' database are:

-> Additional SQL INSERT and SELECT queries, that potentially can impact on query speed.

-> Cost of the 'parent' server that will need to be fairly high spec to handle such a volume of concurrent connections.

Given these facts, are there any other con's to taking this approach? Is this system design commonly used?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 designs which seem to be a better fit:

1) Generate UIDs separately on each DB server, just base it on, for example, machine's MAC or something else machine-specific.

2) If you don't plan on expanding much, you can use auto-increment as your ID, just with a shift. Like a clustering approach: say, you have 3 servers. First one will get every third ID, second one, every second ID and so on. Similarly, you can fetch data based on your ID the same way, just vice-versa